# «Десятичный»: как сокращать?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, сокращения, наращение

Как правильно слово *десятичный* сократить?

> 10-й.

> 10-чный.

> 10-ный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак (из предложенных вариантов).

С наращением пишутся (сокращаются) только **порядковые** числительные или **сложные** существительные и прилагательные, в составе которых имеется числительное:
**10-й** — десятый;
**10-летний** — десятилетний;
**10-метровый** (10-м — в спецтекстах) — десятиметровый;
**10-миллионный** — десятимиллионный.

[Десятичный](https://gramota.ru/meta/desyatichnyy) (*десят/ичн/ый*) — это прилагательное; основанный на счёте десятками; действующий на основе десяти символов. *Д-ая система мер и весов. Д-ая система счисления. Д-ые весы Д-ые дроби.*

Если уж очень хочется сократить (в каком-то особенном тексте), то можно использовать такое же написание, как в словаре — ***д-ый*** (но такое сокращение обязательно должно быть оговорено или в самом начале текста, или в отдельном списке сокращений).

[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kogda-nuzhny-bukvennye-narashcheniya-posle-tsifr)